# undefined reference to Direct3DCreate9@4'

Tags: c++, directx, undefined-reference

I have a problem with Code::Blocks **(version 13.12)** with TDM-GCC compiler **(version 4.7.1, 32 bit)** and DirectX SDK june_2010.

I managed to link these DirectX libraries with my project somehow, at least it's not showing **cannot find -ld3dx9** anymore.
Now I get **undefined reference to Direct3DCreate9@4'** and it shows undefined reference to every Matrix function.

Is this wrong/incompatible DX library linking related issue with codeblocks?

I googled many sites with people having the same issues, but these solutions didn't help me. I remember last year when I worked with DX I had similar problems and I was able to solve them, but now I can't find anything. Is it possible that Code::Blocks and its compiler version changes caused this?

Most of solutions I found : 
use **#pragma comment** and
link in **project->build options**.
As I told, I did both of these things and no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: What library are you using? The one from ms sdk or the one provided by the gcc compiler?

Comment: If you mean what DirectX library then the one from MS DirectX SDK.

Comment: I had the same problem with the mingw lib files. I manualy linked the two files `d3d9` and `d3dx9`: project->build options->linker Settings->Add and then browse to the files. I firstly removed the `d3d9` and `d3dx9` lib files that came with the compiler (keep them as back up).

Comment: Nope... I did what you told me, but it still gives me undefined reference errors.