# Direct X 9 - "undefined reference to Direct3DCreate9@4"

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm getting a linking error

> "undefined reference to Direct3DCreate9@4"

when compiling a DirectX 9 program. There have been some answers on other sites regarding what to do, but none of their solutions works.
This problem already has a question on this site, but unanswered.
[undefined reference to Direct3DCreate9@4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288405/undefined-reference-to-direct3dcreate94)

I'm using code::blocks. I have linked d3d9.lib from Microsoft DirectX SDK (manually, so there can be no confusion whether I chose the correct one).

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Export libraries are supposed to be used with vc++.

Comment: @VTT I'm using code::blocks. The build log output is :mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++11 -O2 -IC:\Users\User\Desktop\DIRECTX\ -I"Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include" -c C:\Users\User\Desktop\DIRECTX\DIRECTX.cpp -o obj\Release\DIRECTX.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Users\User\Desktop\DIRECTX\ -L"Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x64" -o bin\Release\DIRECTX.exe obj\Release\DIRECTX.o  -s  -lgdi32 -lD3D9 -mwindows

Comment: Verify that your mingw install has the libd3d9.a file available.  I know that mingw-w64 has it.  Careful with the casing.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't link it from mingw files, but from DirectX SDK downloaded from microsoft page https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109

Comment: That was already obvious.  What is not is that the GCC linker can handle .lib files as well as .a files (completely different format), can guess at the filename extension given that it uses .a as a default, looks for d3d9 as well as libd3d9, doesn't mind casing, and why you don't want to use the file that is guaranteed to be compatible.

Comment: @HansPassant It worked. Thanks a lot.